# Does mocking affect your assertion count?

Tags: phpunit

I'm noticing when I use mock objects, PHPUnit will correctly report the number of tests executed but incorrectly report the number of assertions I'm making. In fact, every time I mock it counts as another assertion. A test file with 6 tests, 7 assert statements and each test mocking once reported 6 tests, 13 assertions.

Here's the test file with all but one test removed (for illustration here), plus I introduced another test which doesn't stub to track down this problem. PHPUnit reports 2 tests, 3 assertions. I remove the dummy: 1 test, 2 assertions.

```
require_once '..\src\AntProxy.php';

class AntProxyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    const sample_client_id = '495d179b94879240799f69e9fc868234';    
    const timezone = 'Australia/Sydney';
    const stubbed_ant = "stubbed ant";
    const date_format = "Y";

    public function testBlankCategoryIfNoCacheExists() {
        $cat = '';
        $cache_filename = $cat.'.xml';
        if (file_exists($cache_filename))
            unlink($cache_filename);

        $stub = $this->stub_Freshant($cat);

        $expected_output = self::stubbed_ant;
        $actual_output = $stub->getant();
        $this->assertEquals($expected_output, $actual_output);
    }

    public function testDummyWithoutStubbing() {
        $nostub = new AntProxy(self::sample_client_id, '', self::timezone, self::date_format);
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }    

    private function stub_FreshAnt($cat) {
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('AntProxy')
                     ->setMethods(array('getFreshAnt'))
                     ->setConstructorArgs(array(self::sample_client_id, $cat, self::timezone, self::date_format))
                     ->getMock();

        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('getFreshAnt')
             ->will($this->returnValue(self::stubbed_ant));

        return $stub;
    }
}
```

It's like an assert has been left in one of the framework's mocking methods. Is there a way to show every (passing) assertion being made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After each test method completes, PHPUnit verifies the mock expectations setup during the test. `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::verifyMockObjects()` increments the number of assertions for each mock object created. You could override the method to undo this if you really want by storing the current number of assertions, calling the parent method, and subtracting the difference.

```
protected function verifyMockObjects()
{
    $count = $this->getNumAssertions();
    parent::verifyMockObjects();
    $this->addToAssertionCount($count - $this->getNumAssertions());
}
```

Of course, `verifyMockObjects()` will throw an assertion failure exception if any expectation is unsatisfied, so you'll need to catch the exception and rethrow it after resetting the count. I'll leave that to you. :)

Comment: So the behavior I'm seeing is intentional. There must be good reason for verifyMockObjects() incrementing the assertion counter so I won't override it. I'll live with it, nor do I wish to litter even test code with workarounds. Maybe every but me understands why it is like this, but I am surprised I could find no mention of it anywhere.

Comment: It makes sense when you're using mocks as part of the test: "Calling X will cause it to call Y on the mock. If it doesn't, the test is broken." But when you're using mocks as stubs to make testing easier it's just noise: "Calling X will require calling Y, but it just needs `false` so return that." In the end, I don't use the number of assertions for anything so it doesn't matter.